How to handle transaction rollback with async operations in Spring Boot Test?
I have a test structure like this:
 @Test
 void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 service.testservice();
}

public void testservice(){
  saveService();
}

private void saveSerivce(){
   asyncservice.asyncRun(
       () -> someRepository.save(something);
   );
}

In Spring Boot tests with @Test annotation, transactions are usually rolled back after each test. However, when using async methods for database operations, the transaction context differs from the test transaction, so the data persists after the test.
I've tried cleaning up using @AfterEach:
@AfterEach
void cleanup() throws InterruptedException {
    someRepository.delete(something);
}

But the deletion doesn't work either.
How can I properly handle cleanup for async operations in my tests?
Important note: not using "TRUNCATE table"
I only want to delete specific test data, not all data in the table.
Thank you
 @Test
 void test() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

 service.testservice();
}

public void testservice(){
  saveService();
}

private void saveSerivce(){
   asyncservice.asyncRun(
       () -> someRepository.save(something);
   );
}

@AfterEach
void cleanup() throws InterruptedException {
    someRepository.delete(something);
}

